# Bytestring to Image in python

Tags: python, image

I'm using an API that retrieves media, but the API returns the media as a bytestring...I want to save the bytestring as an image. How do I do this?

i've tried this:

```
data = *bytestring*

f = open('image.jpg','w')
f.write(str(data))
f.close()
```

and this compiles successfully, but when I check image.jpg...it is empty or "can't be opened because it is an unknown format"

Comment: don't use `str()`. It may corrupt the data on Python 3. It is pointless on Python 2 if `data` is a bytestring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
f = open('image.jpg','wb')
f.write(data)
f.close()
```

Why? By default, python convert line ending it found to what is used by the underling platform (on windows for example, it convert `'\n'` to `'\n\r'`), which will screw-up you file.

It always consider files to be text files unless you tell explicitly its binary by adding the 'b' option in open(). If you uses the 'b' option it will not convert line endings.

And for the syntax aspect, it is way better to write (it will close the file even in case of exception):

```
with open('image.jpg','wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: hm, this is giving me a TypeError and saying that "must be string or buffer, not bool"...I don't understand why though? The API is returning a byte string like this: "1413467782965" and I typed your response exactly